# keeps getting W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null! error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, runtime-error, android-binder

I am getting the `W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!` message in the log every time a new activity gets created in Android studio emulator.

If anyone can help me that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Flutter 3.3.8; Framework revision 52b3dc25f6; Engine revision 857bd6b74c; Tools Dart 2.18.4, DevTools 2.15.0.